# How to get the text value of a label inside a gridview by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get the text value of label. This label is placed in gridview. Then how i can get it's value on a button click through Jquery. The button is also placed inside the gridview.

Here is my code :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblBEid" Text='<%# Eval("BusinessEntityID") %>' runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modified Date">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" Text='<%# Eval("ModifiedDate") %>' runat="server" />
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" Text="Click Here" runat="server" OnClientClick="getValue();" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You add css names to the label, then from the point that is clicked, you find the first tr father element, and then the fist label with that css name after that tr element.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html as well?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this one will work. But its just raw code. I haven't tested it.

```
    //LinkButton
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" Text="Click Here" runat="server" OnClientClick="getValue(this);" />

     //function
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getValue(element){
            var tr = $(element).closest('tr');
            var ID = $(tr).find('span[id*="lblBEid"]').text();
            var Name = $(tr).find('span[id*="lblName"]').text();
            var Date = $(tr).find('span[id*="lblDate"]').text();
            alert(ID+','+Name+','+Date);
        }
    </script>
```

Its better if you can give a css-class to each of your row.
Like:
     RowStyle-CssClass="grid-row"

Then I can change my code to:

```
var tr = $(element).closest('.grid-row');
```

and will be more stable

Answer (score 0):

You need **[RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)** event where you can access each row created by asp.net.

**In code behind**

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
       LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("lnk");
       Label lblName= (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblName");                      
       lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "getValue(" + lblName.ClientID + ");"
    }

 }
```

**In javascript**

```
function getValue(lblId)
{
     alert($(lblId).text());
}
```